# unable to display status for according id using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In my app I wan to see order status when I click the button. I get status after click button but all status show in first order row.

**php:**

```
<?php
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT o.orderid,o.product,o.ddate,o.pdate,k.kalibariname,o.status FROM orderinfo o,kalibariinfo k WHERE o.clientid = '$clientid' AND o.kalibariid=k.kalibariid");
    while ($rowc = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      echo "<div class='panel panel-default' style='font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;'>
              <div class='panel-heading'>
                <div class='row'>
                  <div class='col-md-4'>
                    ORDER PLACED : <br><b>$rowc[2]</b> 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='panel-body'>
                <div class='row'>
                  <div class='col-md-1'>

                  </div>
                  <div class='col-md-4'>
                    <b style='font-size:22px;'>$rowc[1]</b><br>
                    Sold By : <b>$rowc[4]</b>
                  </div>
                  <div class='col-md-4'>

                  </div>
                  <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <button class='btn btn-default' onclick='tracking($rowc[0])'>Track Order</button>  
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row' id='track'>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>";
    }
  ?>
```

when I click any row button status shown in only 1st row.I want after click button that order status show in that row.

**JavaScript:**

```
function tracking(order){
var orderid = order;
$.ajax({
  url: "tracking.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {orderid:orderid},
  success: function(data){
    $('#track').html(data);
  }
});
}
```

**another php:**

```
<?php
 require "../connectdb.php";


$orderid=$_POST["orderid"];

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT product FROM orderinfo WHERE orderid='$orderid'");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

echo "<div class='col-md-12'>
        $row[0]
        </div>";
?>
```

I want to show that status after click button only.I don't understand where is the problem in my code.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> when I click any row button status shown in only 1st row

May be just because you missed a loop:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   echo "<div class='col-md-12'>$row[0]</div>";
}
```

Comment: @ArpanSarkar, did you made changes in your second php? also can you cross check the sql query fired from php and backend if both are pointing to same database schema and has same row count?

Comment: yes i change 2nd php..I added while loop..but already that dive in while loop in 1st php...It does not work